# Typing of Redux custom observeStore-function

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I am trying to convert a Redux-implementation to Typescript, but are having difficulties making our [observeStore Utility-function](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) typesafe.

This is the original function:

```
function observeStore(store, select, onChange) {
  let currentState;

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState);
    }
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

- How do ensure that the `select`-function actually returns a part of the state (typically a nested object or value)?
- How do I pass the returntype from the `select`-parameter to the `onChange`-parameter?

I have unsuccessfully tried something like this:

```
function observeStore(store: RootState, select: (RootState) => PartOf???<RootState>, onChange: (ReturnType<typeof select>) => void): Unsubscribe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types depend on the type of the selected value, so you need to use a generic function.  I am assuming based on your try that `RootState` is a known value, so the only generic that we need is for the selector's return type.

- `store` is the entire store (not the state) so we use the `Store` type imported from redux with the state generic set to `RootState`
- `select` is a function that selects something from the state, so it takes `RootState` and returns `T`
- `onChange` is a function that takes the selected value `T` and returns `void`
- `currentState` is the selected value `T`, but it is initially `undefined`.

```
import {Store, Unsubscribe} from "redux";

function observeStore<T>(
  store: Store<RootState>,
  select: (state: RootState) => T,
  onChange: (selected: T) => void
): Unsubscribe {

  let currentState: T | undefined;

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState);
    }
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mMyaQm)